# Get linked manufacturer name on product page and listing page above product title on Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, manufacturer

On magento 1.9, I could achieve this with this code

```
<a href="<?php echo strtolower ($manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')) ?>.html"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?></a>
```

but don't know how to do for Magento2.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have assigned "manufacture" attribute to appropriate Attribute Set.

Also, select manufacture for the product as well.

You can get attribute text by using below code.

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

if `$_product` doesn't work for you then try below code to get product data.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

OR

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

Accept if this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: this only gives manufacturer name output.

Comment: for manufacturer individual page(.html), you'll have to use some paid plugins. I dont think so magento 1 or 2 provides default functionality like as you wanted.

Comment: the link I posted could achieve what I wanted, without paid plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code I used for 1.9 was working for Magento2 as well. I used firstly in a phtml file in which

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

this was not given. That is why it didn't work.

So to get the linked manufacturer name on product page, you can use this code.

```
<a href="<?php echo strtolower ($manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')) ?>.html"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?></a>
```